# Retrieve months value from time slicer option in Excel 2017

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have excel sheet for which I have inserted time slicer for the data. It's working just fine. However, my requirement is that, when I select any value in slicer (say Months, Year, Quarters etc..) I need equivalent months value to be populated in a text box for my calculation purpose. Not sure if there is straight way for this. Any help is appreciated.

Ex - Suppose if I select two quarters in slicer as in screen 1, I should see Months = 6 in cell as screen 2.

Screen #1

[image]

Screen #2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this answer:

1. I use a slicer with named Quarter - Refer Name = "Slicer_Quarter"
2. The answer is imported in Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

Try:

```
Sub Loop_SlicerItems()

    Dim sItem As SlicerItem
    Dim Months As Long

    Months = 0

    For Each sItem In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Quarter").SlicerItems

        If sItem.Selected = True Then
            Months = Months + 3
        End If

        Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Months

    Next

End Sub
```